# Way to auto-remove the watermark when the original watermark image is available

Tags: c#, image, watermark

I have a lot of images that I created a while back, and all of them have the same watermark in the same location. I don't have the originals. I also have the original watermark image that is applied to all pictures.

I have never done this sort of thing before, are they any good approaches to this task?

Comment: Do you have the legal *right* to the images without the watermark?

Comment: W00t! Jon Skeet has spoken! :D

Comment: @Andrew: In most situations where you have the legal right to the original image, you can just ask for it. Can we ask what your situation is, where you're entitled to the original image but can't get it directly?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, do you have a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you apply a watermark over an image, the original data of the image that gets covered by the watermark is gone forever. All you can do is use some blending and interpolation techniques to "guess" the original data. Having the original watermark helps you to identify it easier in your images. Maybe you can use the [AForge](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/smoothing_filters.html) .NET library to accomplish the task.

Comment: thank you for your post. I researched the AForge, but seems like that it does not do the watermark removal.

Comment: I don't think that you can find a generic sollution to your issue. Just think about what you're asking for. It will help us get a clearer image of what you're trying to remove if you add some screenshots. AForge will help you filter the watermarked zone in some nice ways and, if the watermark is small or translucent, you can end up with an image that is hard to distinguish from the original (as in the example that I posted). You definitely can destroy the watermark, if this is what you're aiming for, but you will never get back the original image with 100% accuracy.

Comment: I have sees photoshop cs5 videos; therefore there is some way :) I am still searching :) Now this is the question of principle.

Comment: I saw those impressive videos myself and I know what you mean, but if you take the original image (without the watermark) and the photoshopped image, with the watermark removed and compare them pixel by pixel, you will always get some discrepancies, even though the naked eye can't distinguish them.