# Can I remove watermark from image programmatically using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, image, rubygems, watermark

I need to clean my images of watermark.  I know that I can do it using Photoshop or other soft with the same functionality, but I'm interested in automating this feature.

I know that watermark is just logo on added to image layer. I know that ruby language have many gems, which works with images. For example, rmagik, paperclip and other.

I try to Google information about how delete watermark from image using Ruby, and don't found any positive answers. I read rmagik and paperclip gems wiki and as I understand, I can't delete watermark from image using it.

I know, that using carrierwave gem I can put watermark on image:

```
    img.write('composite.gif')
```

For example, I cat put image with watermark to Google image search, parse results of search and get this image without watermark. It will be very bad hardcore-style way answer, 
but it will be answer! and this answer will give me some results.

Maybe I there is some methods for deleting watermark? Does other gem exists with this functionality? Maybe I don't understand something right in rmagik and paperclip gems wikis? Maybe someone have the same problem? So, that's why I am asking for help.

P.S.1: My question demonstrate understanding of the problem being solved. I don't ask for recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource. I ask: how can I resolve my problem programmatically and using ruby  ( see title of question if you don't understand ). But sometimes using some tool or library can resolve some problem!

P.S.2: And if I need to repeat: I don't violate any ownership rights. It's just scientific question.

Comment: How would such library distinguish watermark from the original graphics? What algorithm are you sure that exists?

Comment: Why did you decrease vote of this question? o_O I realy can't google info to resolve my problem. If my question have some analog ( ruby analog ), please give some link!!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @sawa, I can write algorithm with myself, I need library(gem) with API to find watermark and delete layer with watermark from image.

Comment: Downvoted because you should obtain the un-watermarked images in most normal activity. The watermarks are an expression of image ownership, and if you have legitimate use for the images without watermarks, that *usually* comes with access to the non-watermarked versions.

Comment: @sawa, library distinguish watermark... for exmaple, rmagic can resize image. images have data structure inside, have layers, watermark is just an image on added layer. I'm searching gem to do smth like WaterMarkFinder.find('watermark.jpg').delete_from('my_image.jpg') :))))

Comment: OK, I'll post this question om russian forums.

Comment: Photoshop and Gimp also available on Macs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally watermarks will not be in a separate layer, they are be merged before saving image in image editing software such as Photoshop or Gimp.

There is no way you can clean it using Ruby/Imagemagick libraries.

Comment: thanks a lot! Do you now some opensorse program  like Photoshop/Gimp for unix-like OSes ( I'll try to find and use code form them ) ? Or maybe you now some free soft for mac?

Comment: It will be perfect to remove watermarks from many images intime :)

Comment: Many software could remove watermark from image. any software have source code. So there is a way to clean watermarks, I'm just in need to find it.

Comment: Hey Gimp is an opensourse and a great choice for image editing. But, as I mentioned earlier you can't differentiate watermark pixels from an image using any algorithm.
FYI If you want to play with the code Gimp has a ruby scripting plugin (https://git.gnome.org/browse/gimp-ruby/)

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723911/way-to-auto-remove-the-watermark-when-the-original-watermark-image-is-available?rq=1. but it's not ruby way AND HIS VOTE ISN'T < 0 :(.

Comment: sorry @user2830153, but I don't beleave that there is no way to clean it using Ruby. Ruby can everything ;)

Comment: @bmalets: user2830153 is correct, there is no way to do what you want in the general case. **If** the watermark you wish to remove is always the same, and you know the algorithm used to combine it with the original image, this is possible to reverse, up to a limit. But that "if" at the beginning of the sentence is important - gem publishers are very unlikely to create a library just for removing one type of watermark. In short a graphic artist could maybe remove a few dozen different watermarks, in the time it would take you to write some code to remove just one type.