# Remove watermark from tiff image

Tags: c#, pdf-rasterizer

I have generated a TIFF image from a PDF using `Tallcomponents.pdfrasterizer.net.dll`. The TIFF image contains a watermark containing an URL to their site printed diagonally.

How do I remove the watermark?

Comment: They probably want you to purchase a license in order to remove the watermark. Image reconstruction is a hard problem, too broad for SO. Search the site for "remove watermark" to find a few questions addressing this issue, like [Way to auto-remove the watermark when the original watermark image is available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723911/).

Comment: Buy the full version?

Comment: I think this question is not really off-topic, but needs some more explanation from the OP to show what's his coding issue is.

Answer (score 5):

There is probably a problem with your license if you ever bought one. See the [license troubleshooter](https://www.tallcomponents.com/license-troubleshooter.aspx) on the website of tallcomponents.

You can intialize the license using this code.

```
TallComponents.Licensing.LicenseCollection.Add("PDFRasterizer.NET 3.0 Client Component Key", "your_license_key");
```

Comment: Does this answer the question? (no matter that such a question should not be answered in the first place on moral grounds).

Comment: Should be a simple comment

Comment: I disagree with the gentlemen above: _"Buy and configure a license"_ is _a_ perfect answer to _"How to remove watermark"_.

Comment: Note that you also must make sure that the AssemblyProduct and AssemblyCompany are correctly set up, since they are related to the key. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663252/rastered-pdf-not-displaying-correctly/46663309