# Rastered PDF not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, pdf-rasterizer

We have a license on PDFRasterizer, but after re-factoring the code we get a slash through the image:

[image: Picture with slash]

To active the key, the C# code configures the license as described in [Stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016407/remove-watermark-from-tiff-image/21016452#21016452):

```
const string TALL_COMPONENTS_LICENSE_KEY = "SOMETHING-NOT-TO-BE-SHARED";
TallComponents.Licensing.LicenseCollection.Add("PDFRasterizer.NET 3.0 Client Component Key", TALL_COMPONENTS_LICENSE_KEY);
```

How do I correctly configure the license again to remove the slash through the picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reconstructing from version control, it seems that the AssemblyInfo.cs must be configured correctly too.

The AssemblyProduct must be set to your product name as on the license key and the AssemblyCompany must be set to your company name.

The code has been extended to read:

```
const string TALL_COMPONENTS_LICENSE_KEY = "SOMETHING";
TallComponents.Licensing.LicenseCollection.Add("PDFRasterizer.NET 3.0 Client Component Key", TALL_COMPONENTS_LICENSE_KEY);

Assembly callingAssembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
AssemblyProductAttribute product = callingAssembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyProductAttribute>();
AssemblyCompanyAttribute company = callingAssembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyCompanyAttribute>();

if (product.Product != "CONSTANT1")
{
    throw new Exception("The product in the assembly is incorrect.");
}

if (company.Company != "CONSTANT2")
{
    throw new Exception("The company in the assembly is incorrect.");
}
```

The picture no longer contains a slash:

[image: Picture without slash]

When you don't know the company or product name expected, you can log on to take pdf rasterizer site and look at the name of the license. The text after 'assigned to' consists of the company name, a separating underscore and the expected value for assembly product name.

It seems wise to always check the assembly product and company, since it so easy to forget that they are used for license checks when reconfiguring your software project. And the slash is not directly visible when not explicitly testing for it. In this way, the license configuration problem surfaces directly on the first test.